# Not sure how to round off to two decimal places

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have written code to work out the distance between points. What would i need to type in order to get rFinal rounded off to two decimal places?

```
rtotaldist := arcCos(sin(degtorad(rhouselat))*sin(degtorad(rcachelat))
+cos(degtorad(rhouselat))*
cos(degtorad(rcachelat))*cos(degtorad(rhouselong-rcachelong)));
rfinal := rdistperdegree*rtotaldist;


pnlclose.Caption:=('That cache is exactly ' + floattostr(rfinal) + ' KM away')
```

Delphi 2010

Comment: Please re-read your question, whilst pretending you're us, who have no context on your problem.  Do you think it's answerable, other than by guessing?

Comment: Can you tell us what programming language you're using and show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> some_float = 10.10101010101
>>> some_2_decimal_float = round(some_float, 2)
>>> some_2_decimal_float
10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Many languages offer round functions that take a second parameter; that second parameter specifies the number of decimal places you'd like in your answer.

For languages that don't offer that intrinsically, you can do something like this:

```
# I want 2 decimal places, so I'm going to multiply by 10^2
x = x * 100

# Now we round
x = round(x)

# Finally, we divide by 10^2, which is the number we used in the first line.
x = x / 100
```